# How to create a search scope for content type?

Tags: search, search-scope, enterprise-search

As per this tutorial http://velavans.blogspot.com/2010/08/1.html, have created and configured the Metadata on the Search Service in SharePoint 2010.

Note:
Created a list based on the InternalMedia(Item) content type and added few items.

***Steps:***

Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications -> Search service application -> Metadata properties -> New managed Property -> Give the new property a name -> added crawled property mapping to Basic:5(Text) and ows_ContentType(Text) -> "Allow this property to be used in scopes” and “Add managed property to custom results set retrieved on each query” check boxes -> Enabled -> done.

Scopes -> New scope -> New Rule -> Scope Rule Type -> Property Query -> Property Query -> Property Restriction  -> ContentType -> = InternalMedia -> Ok

Content source -> Full Crawl.

Still it does not show any item against the scope, what am I missing here?

[image]

***Update#1:***

while trying to create a New Scope on the site collection, I observed the below

[image]

But not sure why it is not reflecting in the search service application.

Comment: After running a full crawl on the content source, do any of the 'InternalMedia' list items show up in the Crawl Log?   
  

  Also, are you getting any results if you try a simple Content Type, i.e.: ContentType=Document ?

Answer (score 1):

First I would perform a full crawl of the content source containing the start address of your site with the content type. Then, I would troubleshoot this by creating a debug search results page and include the ContentType managed property. Make sure the values are what you expect.

Use the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<xmp><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></xmp> 
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2008/08/28/create-a-xml-test-page-for-search-results/