# Can I search by Content Type without modifying a webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a document named grades.xls with a content type of school.  When someone types in school to the search bar this document does not appear even though the document has a content type of school..

How can I best allow someone to type in school and get this document ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, content type is not included in the crawled properties by default. In order to search by content type you'd need to create a new managed property, and all the other steps involved (search scope, full crawl) for getting a custom property included in the search.

If all the above meant little to you, you need to work with your SharePoint administrator to make it happen.

Comment: teyln..this makes sense as I just added a managed property for a custom column...however i am puzzled as how can Content type be available as a refiner for a search webpart, but is not available as part of a regular search ?  When I go to Managed Properties what field should I select as Content Type seems to be found as part of several fields...  thx

Comment: I think this is what I need to do ?http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/07/03/customizing-fast-search-for-sharepoint-2010-rank-by-content-type/

Comment: What exactly you need to do depends a lot on your SharePoint version and whether or not you use FAST search. Take a look at this [question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113838/how-to-create-a-search-scope-for-content-type)

Comment: We use SP 2013 Enterprise..I will check if we use Fast search..thx